# Trying to add elements to a list when looping into another list java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a code with 2 lists:

```
final List<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
List<BacktoryObject> todoNotes = response.body();

for (BacktoryObject todo : todoNotes) {

}
```

I just want to loop into todoNotes and add elements to imageList for example like:

```
List<BacktoryObject> todoNotes = response.body();

for (BacktoryObject todo : todoNotes) {
   imageList.add("hello");
}
```

but it didn't work and nothing added to `imageList` and I'm 100% sure my for loop works perfectly. What should I do for this?

Comment: Are you sure that response.body() doesn't return an empty list ?

Comment: @Jerry06 no, that's not it. You can still add elements to a final List.

Comment: what doesn't work exactly your code seems fine

Comment: @LakshmikantDeshpande that was also my first idea. Add a System.out.println() statement, or a log line, or debug on the line within the for loop to see if it is ever executed. If todoNotes is empty, it won't be...

Comment: Check if the array does have elements by doing _System.out.println("todo size: "+todoNotes.size());_.

Comment: array has 2 elements i checked it before and im sure

Comment: @Jerry06,
You can still add elements to a list. But you won't be able to use new operator to re instantiate the list.

Comment: shorthand way to add all the elements from one list to other would be, `imageList.addAll(todoNotes);`
For loop is not needed

Comment: Need more info! This code looks fine, which means you must be having some kind of issue elsewhere... are you setting breakpoints or printing any kind of logs?

Comment: Check place in your code, where you initialize your imageList. May something make an clearing this list before you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, your code should work fine. You can try this though. It does the same thing, but much faster.

```
int n = todoNotes.size();
while (n-- > 0) imageList.add("hello");
```

Comment: This is another approach. Actual question is " what is problem with this program ?"

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir Well the actual question is "What should I do for this?", and I think providing another approach was the best way to answer, especially if it works, since there's no obvious bug in the OP's approach, it just "didn't work".  If you have a solution to the bug though, you can post it. It would help.